# Run commands in parallel in bash script

Tags: bash, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a script.sh file something like this:

```
python3 utility.py query-1.json 
python3 utility.py query-2.json
python3 utility.py query-3.json
.
.
```

I am currently using `sh script.sh`  to run the script, this however runs each command in a sequential order. I am new to the concepts of parallelism, I would really appreciate any pointers to study more about it in this context, also is there any bash way of achieving multiprocessing or parallelism here ?

Comment: Put your jobs in the background with `&` (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask each statement to run in the background which could achieve what you want:

```
python3 utility.py query-1.json&
python3 utility.py query-2.json&
python3 utility.py query-3.json&
...
wait
```

The `wait` command makes the script run in the foreground until all background tasks have completed.

If you want more control, for example run one statement per CPU core, you could take a look at [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
cat script.sh | parallel
```